# How do I get minidom to ignore namespaces?

Tags: python, xml

I am using minidom in Python and I'd like getElementsByTagName() to match elements purely by tag-name and ignore any namespaces. The documents are being parsed by minidom.parseString(). Is it possible?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`getElementsByTagName` does match elements purely by tagName.

Do you mean you want to match purely on localName? ie. the part of the tag name after the `:` (if any)? If so use the DOM Level 2 Core method [getElementsByTagNameNS](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/core.html#ID-getElBTNNS):

```
els= document.getElementsByTagNameNS('*', 'tag')
```

Comment: Thanks - the NS one worked, but the non-NS one different. SO I'm guessing there must be some circumstances where they are different.